# jCarousel - update carousel items without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, jcarousel

I'm using the jCarousel plugin for a small gallery page with the itemloadcallback parameter to dynamically load the items on the carousel.

However, I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way by which a carousel instance on a page itself can be removed and recreated with new set of items? I am planning to use a filter (select box) on the page at the onchange of which, I would like to generate a new carousel with the filtered list. Any ideas experts?

Thx in advance.

Za

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd managed to work on it later the same day but was too busy over the past few days to post the solution I came upto. I used the same addItemCallback function that is required to load items dynamically - but on a different event that's bind to the onChange event of the year filter. Well, here it is and I hope it might help a few other trying to implement the same thing:

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {

```
  jQuery('#filter_year').live('change', function() {
    jQuery.get(
        'dynamic_ajax_php.php',
        {
            first: carousel.first,
            last: carousel.last+1,
            year:""+$(this).val()+""
        },
        function(xml) { 
            mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, carousel.first, carousel.last, xml);
        },
        'xml'
    );
});
```

}

The answer would sound too particular to the question (well the question was too particular too) - but the thing I wanted to show is how events from elements outside of the carousel can be tracked and used to manipulate the carousel.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the jCarousel in a div with specific ID (although that's probably how you do it). You only need ajax to load new content. If ajax call succeeds, you can append (or rather just use jquerys' html() function) the necessary structure and invoke jCarousel to that div.

Comment: Sharoni - that's what I mean - invoke jCarousel to a content in a div - Although my content in the div would comprise of the basic structure jCarousel calls for, the second invoke of jCarousel intended to implement over the contents of the div is what I'm unsuccessful to achieve at the moment. Thx.

Comment: what if you return already generated jcarousel via ajax call?

Comment: Sharoni - firstly, how do you mean "already generated jcarousel via ajax" ? Are you aware that jCarousel is a javascript plugin and as any other js function - it is applicable only to elements generated / output to the browser (i.e., client side items) ? If you mean replicating the <ul> - <li> structure that jCarousel constructs for an existing list and returning via ajax - well that does not and will never do the trick because the jcarousel or as a matter of fact any other jquery library needs to apply to an element that already exists on the DOM. Thanks for trying to help, but ..hmm..(sigh)